# Range of a number in the greatest integer function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I was asked to find the limit of the summation of a series which consisted of variables inside the greatest integer function. My textbook says the following :-

For any integer $k$ , we will have

$kx-1 < [kx] ≤ kx$

I was able to verify this for small numbers like $3,4$ etc.

Also for the next sum says

For any integer $k$ , we will have

$k^2x-1 <[k^2x] ≤ k^2x +1$

now i am confused as to why the additional +1 appears on the upper limit in case of  $[k^2x]$ but not  $[kx]$. If , for instance if we're asked to find the range of $[k^3x]$ how would I derive it ? Thanks for your help

note $[.]$ represents the greatest integer function

Comment: Actually, we trivially have the better $x-1<\lfloor x\rfloor\le x$

Comment: Of course this also implies $\frac{\tan\alpha+42}{\sqrt 16-t}-1<\lfloor \frac{\tan\alpha+42}{\sqrt 16-t}\rfloor \le \frac{\tan\alpha+42}{\sqrt 16-t}$, i.e., there is nothing to show

Comment: But then why does it change for the squares

Comment: Hint: let $x=n +w $ where $n =[x] $ and $w $ is the fractional part of $x $. Then $kx =kn +kw $ and $[kx]=kn+[kw] $.

Comment: I just wanted to know why did the upper limit change in case of the squaring $k$ ?

Comment: @fleablood thanks, but how does it help in changing the upper limit ?

Comment: If $a\le b$, then it is also true that $a\le b+1$.

Comment: @Gerry I’m sorry I didn’t understand what you mean

Comment: @gerry I mean , how does it relate to the context of the problem ?

Comment: You are asking, Aditi, why there's a $+1$ in one inequality, and not in the other. @Hagen has pointed out that the inequality with the $+1$ is still true even without the $+1$, so there's no good mathematical reason for putting in the $+1$, and I'm pointing out that if the inequality is true without the $+1$, then it's also true with the $+1$, so  it's perfectly OK to have the $+1$ in there. I think between us, we've said about all there is to be said about the $+1$. If you want to know why the author put in the $+1$, you have two options: (continued, next comment)

Comment: (continued from previous comment) 1) you can read the rest of the chapter to see whether the $+1$ comes in handy in some later calculation, or 2) you can write to the author of the textbook and ask her why she put in that unnecessary $+1$.

Comment: @Gerry oh sorry . You’re absolutely right. So is it safe to assume that in the case of $[k^3x]$, $k^3x-1<[k^3x]≤k^3x+1$ ?

Comment: Look at what @Hagen wrote. It is safe to assume that ${\rm aardvark}-1<[{\rm aardvark}]\le{\rm aardvark}$, no matter what you stick in for aardvark, and then it is safe to add $1$ to the rightmost term.

Comment: @Gerry okay thank you very much hahaha